# How do I print out a set of information at once in python?

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner I tried making a contact book program but this is the problem, I
want to add search-like feature so after I add a contact name, phone number, email and store
it to another file(contact.txt) I want to access it and print it via search.

example:

Name: Johan
Phone: 036902480157
Email: Johan@Email.com

I want to access all the information regarding Johan just by typing his contact name or his phone number, how I can do that?

note: I want to print the name, phone number, and email in each different line

Thanks in advance

my code

```
import os

def head():
    print("")
    print("========================")
    print("      Contact Book      ")
    print("========================")

def restart():
    response = input("\nOpen menu again? (yes/no): ").lower()
    if response == "yes":
        task()
    else:
        print("\nSee You next time!")

def task():
    head()
    done = False
    print('''1. Add Contact
2. Search
3. View Contact List
4. Delete All Contact
5. Exit''')
    while not done:
        task = input("\nWhat do You want to do? (1-5):")
        if task == "1":
            print("\nAdding a new contact!")
            with open('contact.txt', 'a') as f:
                name = input("Name: ")
                phone = input("Phone Number: ")
                if not phone.isnumeric():
                    while not phone.isnumeric():
                        print("Invalid input, please enter only a number!")
                        phone = input("Phone Number: ")
                email = input("Enter an email: ")
                f.writelines(('\n',('=' * 15),'\nName: ',name,
                              '\nPhone: ',phone,'\nEmail: ',email,'\n',('=' * 15)))
                print("\nContact is saved!")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "2":
            with open('contact.txt', 'r') as f:
                search = input("\nSearch: ")
                for i in f:
                    if search in i:
                        print(i)
                else:
                    print("\nNo info was found!")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "3":
            if os.path.getsize('contact.txt') == 0:
                print("\nNo contact info available!")
            else:
                with open('contact.txt', 'r') as f:
                    print("\nAll Contact Info")
                    for i in f:
                        print(i,end="")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "4":
            with open('contact.txt', 'w') as f:
                print("\nSuccesfully deleted all contact info!")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "5":
            print("See You next time!")
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid input please enter a single number from 1 to 5")
            restart()
   
task()
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: oh I am terribly sorry, I actually very new to Stackoverflow. So could You please tell me how to properly ask for help in stackoverflow

Comment: Read the link above, for more info, consider reading [ask] and [tour]. You can [edit] your question to add the code (instead off the images)

Comment: You should be thinking about using Python dictionaries and then persisting the data (as JSON) to your file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try using dictionary but I don't understand persisting the data (as JSON) like You mentioned.

Comment: What you're trying to write is a simple database application. You should read a tutorial on "Python and SQLite". Most likely, the tutorial will contain an address book implementation as a first example. Using a plain text file (as you are trying) makes everything very difficult - it's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a contact and then searching for this contact prints:

```
Adding a new contact!
Name: mrd
Phone Number: 99
Enter an email: the@ff.com

Contact is saved!
...
                              
What do You want to do? (1-5):2

Search: mrd
Name: mrd                  
                           
                           
No info was found!
```

which is inaccurate as you just fount the name. What you want to do is *save all the contact info in the same line in the contacts.txt*  so when you search for a number *or* a name it will give you back that line and then you can print it as you want.

Alternatively you could hold an in memory dictionary that you persist on exit in a json as suggested and you load when you start your program

---

In answer to the comment

```
    if task == "1":
        print("\nAdding a new contact!")
        # TODO make sure no commas in the input!
        name = input("Name: ")
        phone = input("Phone Number: ")
        while not phone.isnumeric():
            print("Invalid input, please enter only a number!")
            phone = input("Phone Number: ")
        email = input("Enter an email: ")
        with open('contact.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(','.join([name, phone, email]) + '\n')
        print("\nContact is saved!")
        done = True
        restart()
    elif task == "2":
        search = input("\nSearch: ")
        with open('contact.txt', 'r') as f:
            for i in f:
                if search in i:
                    for caption, data in zip(['Name:', 'Phone:', 'Email:'],
                                             i.split(',')):
                        print(caption, data)
                    break # contact was found don't go to the else!
            else:
                print("\nNo info was found!")
        done = True
        restart()
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but how do I print the "Name", "Phone", and "Email" in each different line?

Comment: See edits in the answer @Zeroz - the idea is you store all the contact info in one line and then you print it as you like. Note I also omitted the `if` (while will check for the same condition) and I reduced the scope of the with (you want to open the file only when needed)